# Count number of rows buffered in sqlite result set

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using count function to get the number of rows buffered in a resultset.

But it always returns count as one even if resultset is empty.

Please see the code below:

```
$dbhandle = new SQLite3("sqlitedb_111.db");
$selQuery1 = "SELECT id,dbname,tabname,fieldname FROM scan_results ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT  0,10";
$resQuery1 = $dbhandle->query($selQuery1);
print count($resQuery1);
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881255/count-number-of-rows-buffered-in-sqlite-result-set/24882134#comment38655218_24885835) if you just want to return the count of records you could wrap your query in a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and change `$dbhandle->query` to `$dbhandle->querySingle`.  This will work with or without `LIMIT`.

```
$dbhandle = new SQLite3("sqlitedb_111.db");
$selQuery1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id,dbname,tabname,fieldname FROM scan_results ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT  0,10)";
$resQuery1 = $dbhandle->querySingle($selQuery1);
print count($resQuery1);
```

Comment: thanks your query help me to solve my problem here is my new code :   $selcnt = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM (SELECT * FROM scan_results ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,10)";
 $rescnt = $dbhandle->query($selcnt);
 $row = $rescnt->fetchArray();
print $count = $row['count'];

Answer (score 2):

Result is an array. find the size of the array.

```
    $dbhandle = new SQLite3("sqlitedb_111.db");
    $selQuery1 = "SELECT id,dbname,tabname,fieldname FROM scan_results ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT  0,10";
    $resQuery1 = $dbhandle->query($selQuery1);
    $noofrows=sizeof($resQuery1);
    echo $noofrows;
```

Comment: sizeof function also always returning count as 1 even though total record count is more than 1

Comment: do a vardump and check how ur array looks.

Comment: $resQuery1 is always returning  SQLite3Result Object ( ) but when i call $resQuery1->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) its giving me the resultset

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is an embedded database, i.e., there is no client/server communication overhead.
Therefore, it can return the results dynamically; there is only a single row buffered at any time.

To get the number of result rows, you either have to step through the results, or execute something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (original query)`.

Comment: yes , thats true but problem is in my sql query i am using limit.   so when i am try to execute query like " SELECT count(*) FROM scan_results ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT  0,10 "                         its always returns the total count of entire table and not the count within the limit specified i.e if there is not data in that limit it should return 0

Answer (score 0):

Call numRows() on the result set.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php

```
<?php
$db = new SQLiteDatabase('mysqlitedb');
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name='John Doe'");
$rows = $result->numRows();

echo "Number of rows: $rows";
?>
```

Comment: hi i am using sqlite3 ,in sqlite3 this numRows functions is not working

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I assume there's a reason you don't want to return the results and then count them?