# Unable to get data for the second time from a result set

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, resultset

I would like to know whether result set will hold the returned data from the db after fetching data from result set or not. Below is my code. First time when i execute fetchAll i'm able to get the data. But, when i use fetchAll for the second time it return's nothing. I don't understand why.

What i can guess is after fetchAll may be pointer is located at the end of the result set or the result set might be freed.
Which one of my guess is right...?

```
<?php
$Book_DB =new PDO("sqlite:D:/iAnno.data");
$res = $Book_DB->query("select * from chapter");
$res1 = $res->fetchAll();
$res2 = $res->fetchAll();
print_r($res1);
print_r($res2);
?>
```

Comment: You can copy the data to another variable. You don't need both `$res->fetchAll()`. Example: `$res1 = $res->fetchAll(); $res2 = $res1;`

Comment: Then what about the memory occupied by $res. Will it be freed after fetchAll()

Comment: I do not think that $res holds data. It takes the data from database and returns it directly, when you call fetch() or fetchAll().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cursor is located at the end.

If your database support scrollable results, you can use PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL and then go backward using PDOStatement::fetch(). But I do not think you can simply "reset" the cursor at the beginning and use fetchAll() again.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

> PDOStatement::fetchAll() returns an array containing all of the remaining rows in the result set.

After first `fetchAll` there is no remaining rows.

Comment: That's fair. If it is the case what about the memory occupied by $res. Will it be freed or will it hold the same data.

Comment: @RaviMCA , I think that this answer could give some explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24885835/1503018